# coldfusion checkbox value from sql query

Tags: checkbox, coldfusion

I found a post here on doing this, but now I can't find it. It was something like:

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="distlist" checked="<cfif #phlst_DistList# EQ Y> yes <cfelse> no </cfif>">
```

(#phlst_DistList# gets it's value from a cfquery)

I don't get any CF errors, but the form where the query results appear is blank. If I change the cfinput type to text, everything works OK, and I get a Y in the text field.

Thinking it was a SQL problem, I changed the data type of the field from char(1) to bit and replaced the Y in that field with a 1, changed my input tag to:

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="distlist" checked="<cfif #phlst_DistList# EQ 1> yes <cfelse> no </cfif>">
```

But I get the same result, a blank form.

What am I missing here?

Mahalo

Comment: The way your if statement is structured you're comparing the database value to the variable Y. It's also selected="selected" or simply just `selected`

Comment: @MattBusche, you are correct about comparing the values (there should be at least single quotes around `Y`), but the `checked` and `selected` attributes work differently for `<cfinput>` etc. than for standard HTML `<input>` etc.

Comment: Ew, didn't even notice the cfinput. Like you said in your answer no reason to use it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how CFML works. Read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html#notexecuted, specifically the bit entitled "CFML does not get executed". Based on that knowledge: revise your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you eschew `<cfinput>` as well as the other `<cfform>` tags; they're not worth the trouble.

That said, I don't know if you can use `<cfif>` inside of a `<cfinput>` tag. I think you have two options, one:

```
<cfset isChecked = "no" />
<cfif phlst_DistList EQ "Y">
    <cfset isChecked = "yes" />
</cfif>
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="distlist" checked="#isChecked#">
```

Note the conditional can be compressed using the ternary operator `?:`:

```
<cfset isChecked = phlst_DistList EQ "Y" ? "yes" : "no" />
```

Which leads me to the second option:

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="distlist" checked="#(phlst_DistList EQ 'Y'?'yes':'no')#">
```

Comment: *changed the data type... to bit and replaced the Y in that field with a 1* BIT is a better choice for storing boolean values IMO. If it is a non-nullable field, all you need is `<cfinput type="checkbox" name="distlist" checked="#phlst_DistList#" >`.  Though you might consider a more intuitive variable name, like "IsSomething". Also, as David mentioned, the CF controls are a bit old and clunky.  Generally it is better to use the standard html elements instead.

Comment: `BIT is a better choice for storing boolean values IMO` - If one is using SQL Server (which admittedly the OP seems to be), yes. :) If one is using Oracle, OTOH, then there are a plethora of options for a logical true/false.

Comment: (Edit) Could be MySQL too :) I am not sure what would be the best choice for Oracle, but `bit` makes a nice choice given how easily 1/0 can be used in boolean expressions in CF.  Even shorter than using a ternary operator. Plus it has high readability IMO :)

Comment: Amazing!! I've posted on the Adobe ColdFusion Community in the past and never got responses like I get here, thanks so much. Ultimately I'm going to have about 5 or 6 of these checkboxes, we use them to control access to applications. Instead of using a number cfif's should I do this as a struct, or some other means. Also, I had planned on setting the default values for these as a client scope in a .cfc (already doing that with some other client/session scopes) Do you see any problems in doing that? My backend is SQL by the way. Thanks again.

Comment: All depends on your app. There is more than one way to do things. IMO, designing the right database structure is more important than whether you use cfif or a structure. I tend to use a row based approach for permissions, rather than individual column flags, ie AllowX, AllowY. But that is really a separate topic. If you have different question about a specific section code, you should open a separate thread. Just try and keep it [on topic for S.O.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It works differently than a forum, so "opinion based questions" tend to get closed quickly ;-)

Comment: Thanks Leigh, the applications are already written, mostly very simple apps with a couple of view/edit pages and an action page, so I am a bit constrained in what I can and can't do. Mostly I'm just trying to tie all these scattered apps to a common user interface and then limit access from there. Let me get this checkbox deal figured out and I'll be back when I can be more specific.